# fluentbit excluding liveness and readiness

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, fluentd

I am sending logs from my K8s cluster to elasticsearch using fluenbit.
When I look at kibana, I see a lot of entries for liveness and readiness from all of the cluster pods that don't apply to me. Because of this, I've tried to stop my elasticsearch cluster from getting these kinds of messages by using the fliter section as follows:

```
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Daemon Off
        Flush 5
        Log_Level error
        Parsers_File /fluent-bit/etc/parsers.conf
        Parsers_File /fluent-bit/etc/conf/custom_parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server On
        HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port 2020
        Health_Check On

    [INPUT]
        Name tail
        Path /var/log/containers/*.log
        multiline.parser docker, cri
        Tag kube.*
        Mem_Buf_Limit 50MB
        Buffer_Max_Size 1MB
        Skip_Long_Lines On
        Buffer_Chunk_Size 1M

    [INPUT]
        Name systemd
        Tag host.*
        Systemd_Filter _SYSTEMD_UNIT=kubelet.service
        Read_From_Tail On

    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Merge_Log On
        Keep_Log Off
        K8S-Logging.Parser On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On

    [FILTER]
        Name         grep
        Match        kube.*
        Exclude log .*liveness.*|.*readiness.*
```

I don't know why, but these logs keep showing up in my elasticsearch.
Is there something I've forgotten?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your parser?
I think "log" is not a field. You can use a field from the parser instead of "log"

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
 [FILTER]
          Name        modify
          Match       kube.svc.*
          Rename      log.message log_message

      [FILTER]
          Name        grep
          Match       kube.svc.*
          Exclude     log_message /.*XYZ.*/
```

I think the slash or dots are still not working, the bug is still alive, so you must replace them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue discussed in this [forum](https://forum.newrelic.com/s/hubtopic/aAX8W0000008cM2WAI/disable-log-management-gke-fluentbit). Simply disabling the settings might not work for disabling the logs in case of kubernetes, you need to make changes to the manifest files that contain fluentbit configurations and before applying the manifest file delete the old deployment along with the jobs that contain your old manifest file. Now apply the changes and it creates a new deployment which will have the new fluentbit settings configured.

Comment: I didn't quite understood, can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: @RazMaabari When you are configuring fluentbit it will create a deployment and pods inside your kubernetes cluster, so if you want to change the configs you need to first delete the existing pods and deployment and then make changes to the config file and reapply the manifest file to start a fresh deployment of fluentbit. This will make the changed configuration to apply and will remove unwanted logs.